# how to let eclipse java ingore codes after return

Tags: eclipse, return

I'll have some essays and will return in the middle of program,but when I've written return;
the code after return will be raised as unuseful code, and I can't execute it unless I mark them and after it I have to unmark them, is there any good way to let eclipse close the eye on my redundant code after return?

Comment: Comment it (Ctrl-Shift-C).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to comment out the code, this does the trick:

```
code;
if(true) {
   return;
}
more code;
```